# Dictionary just return part of answer(maybe it is about indent)

Tags: python

```
def main():
    file=[['mississippi', 'worth', 'reading','river'], ['commonplace', 'river', 'contrary', 'ways', 'remarkable']]
    print(set_and_count(file))

def set_and_count(common_deleted):
    sets=list(set(common_deleted[0]))
    for i in range(len(common_deleted)):
        ## make a non-repeated word list
        sets=list(set(sets+common_deleted[i]))
    ## initialize dict
    dict_wordloc={}
    for j in range(len(sets)):
        sublist=[]
        count_time=0
        for k in range(len(common_deleted)):
            if sets[j]  in common_deleted[k]:
                count_time+=1
                sublist.append(k)
                dict_wordloc[sets[k]]=count_time,sublist
    return(dict_wordloc)

main()
```

Problem 1:
the code just return a part of the answer

in the example input file, the keys in the dictionary have to be
'mississippi','worth','reading','river','commonplace','contrary','ways','remarkable'

but when I run the code, it returns:

```
{'remarkable': (2, [0, 1]), 'ways': (1, [0, 1])}
```

and every time I run it, the return things are different

for example, when I run it twice, the outcome is

```
{'contrary': (2, [0, 1]), 'ways': (1, [0, 1])}
```

Problem 2:
The answer is wrong, in the output in Prob 1, in the key `remarkable`, the value has to be `(1,[1])`

the first item in tuple is how many sentences have this word(a nested list is a sentence)

the sencond item in tuple is the sentence NO that contains that word

Comment: You are assuming that we either just grok the context of your question or painstakingly go through your code in order to track down what you actually want to do. Neither are the case. :) Please create a [MCVE] with input examples and the desired output. It's (at least to me) completely opaque what "find the location of the word, and how many sentences have that word" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I edited it ,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use a nested `for` loop to iterate through the words and append the indices generated by `enumerate` to the respective dict entry using the word as the key:

```
d = {}
for i, l in enumerate(file):
    for w in l:
        d.setdefault(w, [0, []])[0] += 1
        d[w][1].append(i)
```

`d` would become:

```
{'mississippi': [3, [0, 7, 8]], 'worth': [1, [0]], 'reading': [1, [0]], 'commonplace': [1, [1]], 'river': [4, [1, 2, 3, 6]], 'contrary': [1, [1]], 'ways': [1, [1]], 'remarkable': [1, [1]], 'considering': [1, [2]], 'missouri': [1, [2]], 'main': [1, [2]], 'branch': [1, [2]], 'longest': [1, [2]], 'seems': [1, [3]], 'safe': [1, [3]], 'crookedest': [1, [3]], 'part': [1, [3]], 'journey': [1, [3]], 'uses': [1, [3]], 'cover': [1, [3]], 'ground': [1, [3]], 'crow': [1, [3]], 'fly': [1, [3]], 'six': [1, [3]], 'seventy-five': [1, [3]], 'discharges': [1, [4]], 'water': [3, [4, 6, 7]], 'st': [1, [4]], 'lawrence': [1, [5]], 'twenty-five': [1, [5]], 'rhine': [1, [5]], 'thirty-eight': [1, [5]], 'thames': [1, [5]], 'vast': [1, [6]], 'drainage-basin': [2, [6, 8]], 'draws': [1, [6]], 'supply': [1, [6]], 'twenty-eight': [1, [6]], 'states': [1, [6]], 'territories': [1, [6]], 'delaware': [1, [6]], 'atlantic': [1, [6]], 'seaboard': [1, [6]], 'country': [1, [6]], 'idaho': [1, [6]], 'pacific': [1, [6]], 'slope': [1, [6]], 'spread': [1, [6]], 'forty-five': [1, [6]], 'degrees': [1, [6]], 'longitude': [1, [6]], 'receives': [1, [7]], 'carries': [1, [7]], 'gulf': [1, [7]], 'fifty-four': [1, [7]], 'subordinate': [1, [7]], 'rivers': [1, [7]], 'navigable': [2, [7, 7]], 'steamboats': [1, [7]], 'hundreds': [1, [7]], 'flats': [1, [7]], 'keels': [1, [7]], 'area': [1, [8]], 'combined': [1, [8]], 'areas': [1, [8]], 'england': [1, [8]], 'wales': [1, [8]], 'scotland': [1, [8]], 'ireland': [1, [8]], 'france': [1, [8]], 'spain': [1, [8]], 'portugal': [1, [8]], 'germany': [1, [8]], 'austria': [1, [8]], 'italy': [1, [8]], 'turkey': [1, [8]], 'almost': [1, [8]], 'wide': [1, [8]], 'region': [1, [8]], 'fertile': [1, [8]], 'valley': [1, [8]], 'proper': [1, [8]], 'exceptionally': [1, [8]]}
```

If you prefer the item values to be tuples instead you can transform `d` with:

```
d = {k: tuple(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why did my code come out with a strange answer? I really can't find anything wrong

Comment: To be frank, I can't quite understand the logic behind your code. If you really would like help with your code you might have to detail your algorithm with pseudo-code or at least more inline comments.